# Change Image.asset opacity using opacity parameter in Image widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-image

I have a simple image that I want to put semi transparent. I have seen some methods to do it, but none of them was talking about the parameter `opacity` of the own `Image.asset` that accepts a widget of type `Animation`. Is it possible to change the opacity permanently with this parameter?

```
Image.asset(
  "assets/images/triangles_small.png",
  height: 380,
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actually, the question point using `opcaity` on `Image.asset`. You can use `AlwaysStoppedAnimation`

```dart
Image.asset(
  "image/link",
  opacity: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(.5),
```

To have animation, you can pass animation here.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use parameter inside the Image widget, you can construct something like this:

```
Image.asset(
        "assets/images/triangles_small.png",
        height: 380,
        opacity: AnimationController(
            vsync: this,
            value: 0.5
        )
      ),
```

But it's better to use @Hippo Fish receipt, to wrap Image inside Opacity widget:

```
Opacity(
          opacity: 0.5,
          child: Image.asset(
            "image/link",
            height: 380,
            width: 380,
          ),
        )
```

Of cause you need to use mixin like

```
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
```

to use vsync: this